# Сделать все меньше

Tags: html, css

Верстал сайт и забыл что все время у меня % в браузере стоял 80. (ctrl и два раза колесиком мыши на себя) теперь когда ставлю нормальный показ (100%) то у меня много чего не попадает на страницу, есть ли вариант как-то весь сайт сделать так чтобы он отображался иначе, сделать все более мелким? Как-то "умостить" чтоли?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Надо было сразу кроссбраузерность делать. Заметил бы

Comment: Можешь попробовать сделать `zoom: 0.9`. Но работает вроде только в хроме. В ФФ точно нет

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно применить `transform: scale(Х);` для изменения масштаба всей страницы, но проверить правильность отрисовки всех элементов.
А лучше менять размер базового шрифта в `% или em`, а к остальным элементам указать дополнительные стили тоже в процентах.

Comment: ерунда выходит :(